# Can't play a sound file downloaded from an S3 bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, avfoundation

I am facing a weird problem with an .m4a sound file on an iOS app written in Swift.

Here is what happens:

- I record a sound file on the device using the app. Let us call it xyz.m4a.
- I check that I can play this sound file, and it is working.
- I then upload the sound file to an AWS S3 bucket, from my app.
- I check on the AWS console that the file is uploaded as expected and I download it using a browser (on my computer), checking again that I can still play the sound as expected. Up to this point nothing is wrong, I can play the sound.
- I then use my app to download the file to my iOS device (iPhone 6). All seems OK here too.
- Finally I try to play the downloaded file from within my app and this is where things go wrong. I cannot play it.

Here is what I think is the relevant code, please let me know if you think I should add more.

Code to download the file from the AWS S3 bucket:

```
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    transferUtility.downloadData(
        fromBucket: "mybucket",
        key: "xyz.m4a",
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler
        ).continueWith {
            (task) -> AnyObject! in if let error = task.error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            if let _ = task.result {
                // Do something with downloadTask.
                print("task.result -- OK!")
                let downloadOutput = task.result
                print("downloadOutput:\(String(describing: downloadOutput))")
            }
            return nil;
    }
```

Here is the completionHandler part:

```
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = {
        [weak self] (task, URL, data, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("transfer completion OK!")
            let localFileName = "xyz.m4a",
            playFileURL = self?.getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent(localFileName)
            FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: (playFileURL?.path)!,
                                           contents: data,
                                           attributes: nil)

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (playFileURL?.path)!) {
                print("playFileURL present!") // Confirm that the file is here!
            }
        })
    }
```

Code to play the downloaded sound file:

```
    let fileName = "xyz.m4a", 
    audioFile = getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioFile.path) {
        print("We have no file !!!!!") // Just in case the file was not found!
    }

    // This code assumes the file exists.
    do {try soundSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try soundSession.setActive(true)

        if audioPlayer == nil {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFile,
                                            fileTypeHint: AVFileType.m4a.rawValue)
            guard let _ = audioPlayer else {return}
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
        }

        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch let error {
        print("Error:\n" + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Finally here is the error I get:

```
Error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)
```

I hope someone can see something wrong an tell me where the problem is.

Comment: The file can be malformed or not a valid instance of an audio file of its type, or not recognized as an audio file.

Comment: Your comment makes perfect sense. The question is: When did it change? Before uploading I can play it, so it is a valid audio file. When it is on the server it is still a valid audio file, as you can see reading my post. Only after I download it does it become invalid. How can we explain that? Can you think of something I did bad?

Comment: In your completion handler you check `if FileManager.default.fileExists(...)`. You'd be safer to check that the call before it (`FileManager.default.createFile(...)`) returns `true`.

Comment: Right you have a point. I just did as you say for checking, but it returns true, so the problem must be somewhere else. Actually I also checked the file was not there before hand.

Comment: Can you share the URL from where you are downloading that file???

Comment: I found some error on my part I need to see if that totally explains my issues.

Comment: And I suppose if I give you the URL you won't have access to it.
Maybe I could copy the file on S3 to somewhere you could try if you want.

Comment: Can you check the file in document directory if it exists and playable after downloading it?

Comment: The exits, but I can't play it.

Comment: your code is perfect. Something is wrong with your file. I have downloaded m4a file using given code. It's working fine.

Comment: I don't know where the file is broken on the process. And it seems the problem appears only if I uploaded the file using PFFile.